# c# ilmerge problem with icons on a dll

Tags: c#, image, assemblies, ilmerge

I have this problem:
in my test.dll I have a usercontrol with a button with an icon png, my test.exe contains the usercontrol in test.dll and everything works fine.
after I use a ilmerge to create testMerged.exe like this:

```
ilmerge /wildcards /t:winexe /out:$(TargetDir)testMerged.exe
$(TargetPath) $(TargetDir)test.dll
```

and the program works fine but the button doesn't have the icon.... how can I solve this?

Comment: WinForms (System.Windows.Forms.Usercontrol) or WPF (System.Windows.Controls.Usercontrol)? How is the icon assigned to the button?

Comment: winforms, is built with visual studio 2008, the icon is a classic transparent png file ( if I launch the test.exe works fine and the icon is on the button, but if I launch the testMerged the button is shown without icon....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I got it to work:

Class Library

- Create new class library
- Create user control
- Add button to user control
- In project properties, add image resource (existing png file)
- Set the Build Action on the png file to Embedded Resource
- Set the button image using

  this.button1.Image = global::ClassLibrary1.Properties.Resources.MyImage;

Win forms

- Create new winform project
- Add reference to the class library project
- Rebuild (to get the user control in the toolbox)
- Add user control to the form
- Set the post Build action to

  "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\ILMerge\ILMerge.exe" /t:winexe /targetPlatform:v2 /out:$(TargetDir)testMerged.exe $(TargetPath) $(TargetDir)ClassLibrary1.dll
- Rebuild
- Run the testMerged.exe

My result:

[Not enough rep to post an image :( ]

Comment: thanks but are exactly the same thing that I made and the image is not shown... seems only a problem with ilmerge, 'cause launching the exe compiled works fine... :(

Comment: @ghiboz how are you setting the image on the button? Have you used ILSpy to see if the image is properly being stored in the merged assembly?

Comment: hmmm no, i don't know ILSpy, I used the designtime, clicked on image on the properties of the button and selected the image into a resource of the project

Comment: Use ILSpy to check if the image is being saved properly. Download ILSpy (it's free) then use it to open your merged assembly, then browse the tree to the resources and you should see your image in there. Click on it, then you should see a 'Save file' button, save the file then try to view it.